# Using IndexRoute to set up a Landing Page in my React App

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to set up a landing page that will then lead to my home page with React. I created a landing page component called `Splash`. I'm trying to use IndexRoute so that my app displays `Splash` as my initial page. This is my `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import App from 'views/App';
import Home from 'views/Home';
import About from 'views/About';
import Cart from 'views/webcart';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={ hashHistory }>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Splash } />
                <Route path='about' component={ About } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
                <Route path='Home' component= { Home }
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,    
    document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

This is my `splash.js` file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Woods from './woods.jpeg';
import Logo1 from './whitestar.png';


export default class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id='Splashwrapper'>
                <img src={Woods}></img>
                <img src={Logo1}></img>
            </div>    
        );  
    }
}
```

My problem is that my app won't display `Splash` at first, my home and landing page display at the same time. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

This is my `Home` component where it might be better to to what I want with the landing page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import Jag from './jag.jpg';
import Jag2 from './jag2.jpg';
import Logo from './nsplogo.jpeg';

var Music = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2> BBB </h2>
                </div>
            );

        }
    });

export default class Home extends Component {
    soundCloud() {
        var SC = require('soundcloud');

        SC.initialize({
            client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'
        });
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            showSquareOne:false,
            showSquareTwo:false,
        }
        this.toggleShowSquare = this.toggleShowSquare.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowSquare(property){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({[property]:!prevState[property]}))
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Home' id='Home'>  
                <div id="musicwrapper" className={this.state.showSquareThree?'':'invisible'}>
                    <div id='musicsquare' className={this.state.showSquareOne?'':'invisible'}>
                        <h1>AAA</h1>
                        <div id="musicpics">
                            <img src={Jag} tabIndex="1" id='jag1'></img>
                            <img src={Jag2} tabIndex="1" id='jag2'></img>
                        </div>
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                        <div id='Body'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='musicMenu'>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="music" onClick={()=>this.toggleShowSquare('showSquareOne')}>Music</li>
                        <li id="shows" >Shows</li>
                        <li id="collections">Collections</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also, my app has a `Menu` component that is always on top of the page, this has been giving me issues with the landing page because despite the landing page being there, the menu is also showing..

Comment: You could just stick the splash screen at the top of the Home page's render function based off a boolean in state, then flip the boolean after a second or two and reveal the regular render. I believe this solution would be cleaner, both from a url perspective and organizationally.

Comment: Maybe you are lacking the slash before your routes: `<Route path='/about' component={ About } />`

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this..plus in my Home page I have on Click switches to display components, so It would be even better for me because I'm trying to have a logo on my landing page that when clicked it shows Home. @MichaelLyons

Comment: I'm going to post my `Home` component, maybe you can help me out with how to get this done.. @MichaelLyons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface**: This is a very basic way of displaying the splash screen. I'm just going to highlight the additions to the component lifecycle required to make this work.

If you use this in your **Home** component, it will render the splash each and every time Home mounts, to have this happen once, it would be better placed in your root **App** component since it will only mount on page load.

First in your constructor state add a key for tracking splash visibility like so:

```
this.state = {
  splash: true
};
```

Then in your **componentDidMount**, add a Timeout with a function that calls `this.setState` with however long you want the splash to be available (Note the Fat Arrow Syntax to maintain `this` reference):

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({splash: false});
  }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
}
```

And finally in your render, check the splash boolean and return the splash div if it is true like so:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.splash) {
    return <div className="splash">Splash</div>
  }
  return (...Default Content...)
}
```

And since you are using Redux, you could place the splash toggle in a store and pass it down to your app.

To add animation for a smooth transition, you could always render the splash screen, and use the boolean to toggle a class that fades it from view and reorders the zindex OR use [React Transition Group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do want it to only load once, not everytime Home loads. So when I add this to my root `app.js` how should I what is supposed to go in the `render()` but in `ReactDOM.render()` ?

Comment: No don't add it to your app.js, add it to the App component that is the root Route component you're using: ```import App from 'views/App'``` <-- In here

Comment: Got it..so if this is my `App.js` https://pastebin.com/vZ3fzgtJ ..I'm not sure how to inject the landing page in my render..

Comment: Having the render function return early with a div is the "injection". If you want another component like ```<Splash />``` to render just import it into your component and place it within the div.

Comment: Oh sorry, the splash value must start as true. Currently it's always false so you wouldn't see it at all. I accidentally set it to false on init in my example.

Comment: I was wondering why it was like that..but I thought it had a purpose lol..now it works! thanks.

Comment: Quick question..if I want to implement an on click function to change from landing page to home,  how can I link an on click function I have  in  `Splash` ...https://pastebin.com/t8WtfaJM and have it trigger `splash: true`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the `Splash` route separately to achieve that.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={ hashHistory }>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Splash } />
                <Route component={Splash} /> // Add this.
                <Route path='about' component={ About } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
                <Route path='Home' component= { Home }
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,    
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: React-router tutorial doesn't specify this.

Comment: @xDreamCoding Can you share the links of the docs you are following?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/08-index-routes